# Convert Option<&&[T]> to Option<&[T]>

Tags: rust

I have a hashmap of type `HashMap<String, &[T]>`.

Calling `hashmap.get(&key)`, returns an `Option<&&[T]>`. [Double ampersand]

How do I convert that to `Option<&[T]>`? [Single ampersand]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `&` references are `Copy`, so you can use [`Option::copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.copied):

```
hashmap.get(&key).copied()
```

Comment: Is that a 'cheap' conversion?

Comment: @Adamarla I'm not sure what "expensive" would be, so... yes, I guess?